Whats the thing with MIND? How to communicate with subconscious mind?
Ive heard in a lot of places that in ancient times, Sages or saints or people like them used to focus more on internal discovery and development than external. Like you know, Body and stuff. What are those developments and how did they achieve it?
What does hinduism talk about the subconscious mind and a
